# How to make serializer accept a data type, but converts it before save operation in DRF?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have the following model and serializer

```
class MyModel(db_models.Model):
  
    name = db_models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = db_models.CharField(max_length=1024, blank=True)
    complex_data = db_models.BinaryField(null=True, default=None)


class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = models.MyModel
        fields = (
            "id",
            "name",
            "description",
        )
```

I use this serializer for CRUD operations, but for creating or updating, I would like the client to be able to input a "complex_data", which consists of arrays and numerical data, it should be valid for the serializer, but before saving the data, I would like the serializer to convert the the complex_data to bytes format (for that I use msgpack), and save the model object with the converted complex_data.

since I only manipulate the complex_data field on create and on update actions, the complex_data should be a write-only field.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can hook into different places to achieve what you want to do.

1. You could create a custom field by sub-classing `rest_framework.serializers.Field` and write a custom `to_representation` method. Just flag you field with `write_only=True` if you don't want it in the response.

Have a look at https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#custom-fields.

2. You could hook into the `create` or `update` methods of your serializer.

```py
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = models.MyModel
        fields = (
            "id",
            "name",
            "description",
        )

    def create(self, validated_data):
        ....

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        ....
```

Have a look at:
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances